# Best way to cache contacts photo

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, android-volley, lru

I'm trying to display all contact list in my activity, what is the best way for showing/caching the contact photos? assuming I have 1000+ contacts and all of them have profile photo.

I already read about [Google volley library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) but it's for loading pictures from HTTP.

Also, I've read the [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) in developer.com.

1. Whats is the difference between the two?
2. what should I use to load contacts profile image?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://square.github.io/picasso/

...............................

```
File file = new File(uri);
        Picasso.with(context).load(file).skipMemoryCache()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.note_fold).into(holder.thumb);
```

Comment: is it possible to load image by contact Uri profile image?